# Does ViewPager require FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an app with actionbar with viewpager, so i'm extending my base activity from FragmentActivity. Is this mandatory? if not what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this mandatory?

Only if your pages will be fragments from the Android Support package's backport of fragments.

> if not what is the alternative?

Don't inherit from `FragmentActivity`, in which case your pages can be simple views, or they can be fragments from the native API Level 11 implementation of fragments.

Comment: but I want to implement viewpager with fragments.. And viewpager requires the base activity extending from FragmentActivity.

Comment: @BlahBlank: "And viewpager requires the base activity extending from FragmentActivity" -- no, it does not. Please re-read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`FragmentActivity` should be used when you are going to use `Fragments`, so you can use `getSupportFragmentManager` and other functions without any problem. If your `BaseActivity` don't use `Fragments`, you can extend just `Activity`.

If you are thinking to add `Fragments` as `ViewPager`'s children you should extends `FragmentActivity` and create something similar to this : [ActionBarSherlock FragmentsTabPager Sample](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java).

Hope this help!

Comment: but API 11 onwards i can use fragments with base activity extending Activity.

Comment: my minSdkVersion is 16, i'm using Viewpager in one of the activity which extends FragmentActivity. When I tried extending the base activity with Activity, it throws errors, I dont understand why?

Answer (score 0):

I think [fragment not necessary for view pager. More detail you can check this link.](http://androiddataplay.blogspot.in/2013/04/simple-view-pager-example.html)

I hope you will success.